# Amazon S3 check existence of bucket using libS3

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, amazon-s3

I am using LibS3, a C library that talks to my amazon S3 server and I have noticed that for checking the existence of a bucket libs3 sends a GET request with a query in the URL "?location", and the amazon S3 server responds with an appropriate HTTP response if the bucket exists or not. The problem is that in the documentation of the Amazon S3 server for checking the existence of a bucket it's said that you must make a HTTP HEAD request, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketHEAD.html, so I'm confused on what method it's used in the server... If the both of them are supported and how is list objects different from check existence using GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can send both GET and HEAD requests to check existence of a bucket. Amazon will return 404 HTTP code if it doesn't exist. The main difference is that HEAD does not contain request body (thus takes less bandwidth).